# Append client_reference_id to stripe trigger webhook

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm currently attempting to test receiving a client_reference_id from Stripe, via a webhook after a checkout session is completed.

Currently, I'm running the test triggers via the Stripe CLI, with this command:

> stripe trigger checkout.session.completed

This successfully calls the endpoint on my backend, and logs the event.

However, in these trigger calls via the CLI, the client_reference_id is blank. I would like to populate this with my site's user id, so I can update my database to mark the user as a premium account.

To do this, I attempted this:

> stripe trigger checkout.session.completed --add
> customer:client_reference_id=1234

Hoping that it would set the id to 1234. However, it stays at null.

Does anyone know what the command is to set the client_reference_id via the Stripe CLI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command you want is:

```
stripe trigger checkout.session.completed --add checkout_session:client_reference_id=1234
```

The `trigger` command ultimately makes a set of API calls defined in a fixture. [Here's the fixture](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/blob/2bf13c1dbc2a3be683d16a54d3e06a0f9e7ed585/pkg/fixtures/triggers/checkout.session.completed.json) for the `checkout.session.completed` event.

The [Stripe CLI reference](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/trigger#trigger-add) mentions that any parameters you add must specify the resource. In this case, you want to add a value for the `client_reference_id` to the `checkout_session` resource that is created when you trigger this event.